# Overload resolution for char*, char array, and string literals using constexpr, SFINAE and/or type_traits

Tags: c++, overloading, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

I have run into an interesting challenge that I have been trying to solve for hours, but after much research and many failed attempts, I find myself asking this question.

I would like to write 3 overloaded functions that each take one of the following types: `const char*`, `const char(&)[N]` and `string literal (e.g. "BOO")`. I understand that a string literal is simply a char array, but please bear with me while I explain my approach.

The two functions below are able to differentiate between the first two types (`const char*` and `const char(&)[N]`) thanks to the wrapper class `CharPtrWrapper`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class CharPtrWrapper
{
public:
    CharPtrWrapper(const char* charPtr)
        : m_charPtr(charPtr)
    {

    }

    const char * m_charPtr;
};

void processStr(CharPtrWrapper charPtrWrapper)
{
    std::cout << "From function that takes a CharPtrWrapper = " << charPtrWrapper.m_charPtr << '\n';
}

template<std::size_t N>
void processStr(const char (&charArr)[N])
{
    std::cout << "From function that takes a \"const char(&)[N]\" = " << charArr << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    const char* charPtr = "ABC";
    processStr(charPtr);

    const char charArr[] = {'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0'};
    processStr(charArr);
}
```

Output:

```
From function that takes a CharPtrWrapper = ABC
From function that takes a "const char(&)[N]" = XYZ
```

Now, if I call `processStr` with a string literal (e.g. `processStr("BOO")`), the version that takes a `const char(&)[N]` gets called, which makes sense, since a string literal is simply a char array.

Here is where I reach the crux of the problem. I have not been able to write a function that is able to differentiate between a char array and a string literal. One thing I thought might work was to write a version that takes an rvalue reference:

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
void processStr(const char (&&charArr)[N])
{
    std::cout << "From function that takes a \"const char(&&)[N]\" = " << charArr << '\n';
}
```

But it turns out that string literals are lvalues. I have also played with different versions that use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_array`, but I still don't get the result I'm looking for.

So I guess my question is the following: is it possible to differentiate between char arrays and string literals in modern C++?

Comment: why? why? do you need this?

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between the two? I don't even think it's possible, but again, what is important about string literals vs `char *`s?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446068/in-c-why-overload-a-function-on-a-const-char-array-and-a-private-struct-wra) question I asked yesterday to understand why I need this. I would like to improve an open source library.

Comment: *I have not been able to write a function that is able to differentiate between a char array and a string literal* A string literal **is** a char array.  They have the exact same type so you can't differentiate them.  It is even an lvalue so you can't differentiate based on lvalue/rvalueness.

Comment: You may be able to achieve your actual goal using `consteval` from C++20, but I don't think there's any way using only C++17.

Comment: Compilers prefer non-template overloads to a perhaps better fitting templated overload. Dont know the reason for this, but it's been the behavior since before C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [[expr.prim.id.unqual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id.unqual):

> [...] The type of the expression is the type of the identifier. The
>   result is the entity denoted by the *identifier*. The expression is an
>   lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and a
>   prvalue otherwise; it is a bit-field if the identifier designates a
>   bit-field ([dcl.struct.bind]).

Therefore, given a declaration

```
const char arr[] = "foo";
```

The expression `arr` is an lvalue of type `const char[4]`.

---

Per [[lex.string]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#8):

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of *n* `const char`”, where *n* is the size of the string as defined
>   below, and has static storage duration.

And per [[expr.prim.literal]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.literal):

> A *litera* is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form. A
>   string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

Therefore, the expression `"foo"` is an lvalue of type `const char[4]`.

---

Conclusion: a function is unable to differentiate between a (const) char array and a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @L. F.! I'm disappointed that this is not possible because I feel like I found a situation in which it would be very beneficial if it were.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this too for optimisation of compile-time string literals. While I don't think there is any standard way to do this in C++, I found that in GCC, Clang and Intel compiler you can at least use the [`__builtin_constant_p` intrinsic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp) to determine if values are constant.

Note that the intrinsic can't be reliably used on the pointer or reference itself (because the constant folding on the pointer currently doesn't work in Clang, and because even constant pointer does not necessarily guarantee constant contents), so the trick is to manually go through the string and verify that each character is a constant:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr bool is_const_str(const char *s) {
    for (; *s; s++) {
        if (!__builtin_constant_p(*s)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool test_dynamic(const char *s) {
    return is_const_str(s);
}

bool test_const() {
    return is_const_str("Hello, world!");
}
```

Here's a Godbolt link demonstrating this working in GCC and Clang:

https://godbolt.org/z/ch89Wd8Yb

You can see in both assemblies that `test_const` was folded into `1` (as in, `true`), while `test_dynamic` was folded into a simple check of the first character (that is, if string is empty, it's considered constant, otherwise not):

```
test_dynamic(char const*):                    # @test_dynamic(char const*)
        cmp     byte ptr [rdi], 0
        sete    al
        ret
test_const():                        # @test_const()
        mov     al, 1
        ret
```

I couldn't find MSVC alternative, but it should be easy to at least add a fallback for MSVC that always returns false, so that the code is still valid and compiles, just doesn't benefit from said optimisations.

Also worth noting that, unlike regular `constexpr` functions, this intrinsic depends on optimisations - that is, it will only return `true` if the compiler can prove that the input characters were all constant, which it can only do after inlining, which doesn't happen in debug mode. As long as you only use it only for own optimisations, it should be fine, but otherwise you can't rely on it returning a predictable result.